# Language switcher in a modal window (pop-up)

Tags: 8, ajax, i18n-l10n

I really got quite far on this issue. Using Drupal 8's Modal API. Having a button in a block that triggers the modal with Drupal's language switcher inside. Everything looks fine EXCEPT for the URLs this modal returns. Every URL gets appended with `?ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=html` which breaks the whole functionality. For example `http://d8.dev/fr/node-41-article?ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=html`.

I also tried it with a Controller instead of a Form. But then the URLs look even worse, since then they only take the controller path to create the langswitch URLs.

I already started to guess I'd need to start over using a more independent approach. But maybe you folks know a way to get it working with my current approach? Is there a way I can simply cut off the query? Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\langswitch_modal\Form\LangswitchModal.
 */

namespace Drupal\langswitch_modal\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\OpenModalDialogCommand;

/**
 * Class LangswitchModal.
 *
 * @package Drupal\langswitch_modal\Form
 */
class LangswitchModal extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'langswitch_modal';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';

    $form['actions']['#type']  = 'actions';
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type'  => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Switch language'),
      '#ajax'  => [
        'callback' => '::open_modal',
      ],
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

  public function open_modal(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $block   = \Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder::lazyBuilder('languageswitcher', 'full');
    $render  = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($block);
    $title   = $this->t('Choose language');
    $content = $render;
    $options = [
      'dialogClass' => 'popup-dialog-class',
      'width'       => '300',
      'height'      => '300',
    ];

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($title, $content, $options));

    return $response;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! All I needed was a little JS to get rid of the query:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  var $link = $('a.language-link');
  $link.each(function(i,el){
    $(el).attr('href', $(el).attr('href').split('?')[0]);
  });
});
```